# In $\Bbb R^3$, is there a general principle governing these "visual" angles?

Tags: geometry, 3d, visualization

I believe most of you have drawn the xyz coordinate system hundreds of times and so have I. You may have drawn it like these, on various occasions:
[image]
(the reverse directions of the axis are not shown.)
All look ok, don't they?

But if you draw like these:
[image]
then they would just look perfectly weird, because you are never supposed to see such things in real life!

Thereby arises my question: is there something to which the "visual" angles in these pictures must conform so that things wouldn't look out of place? Like an inequality or, more probably, a group of them? (well, I don't think it's likely to be equations)
 
Here "visual" angles take their literal meaning, say, if $\angle xOy$ looks like $120$ degrees measured from the picture, then its "visual" angle is $120$ degrees despite the fact that $\angle xOy=90$ degrees. If we denote the "visual angles" of $\angle xOy$, $\angle yOz$ and $\angle xOz$ by $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively, then **does there exist a general principle which they have to fulfil so that picture won't look visually unacceptable**?

---

And by the way, do the "visual" angles have to do with the optics of our eyes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is some general principle for this.  If anything, this is entirely a social construct.  All of the pictures that you have drawn above are valid, and we could probably come up with various surfaces such that each is most easily visualized using each of these "visual angles".

The only thing that might take some getting used to is if you switched the x and y in these images.  The reason this would be weird is because we typically choose the orientation given by "right-hand rule" for $\mathbb{R}^3$.  So, if you chose the alternate orientation ("left-hand rule" I guess?) it would look strange, but it wouldn't necessarily be wrong in any meaningful sense.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the two "strange" ones can arise as orthogonal projections of three mutually perpendicular axes onto an image plane at all.

Comment: But those weird ones certainly are not acceptable in any "social construct" ?

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Agreed. My question is just what it will take to make a visually valid projection image.

Comment: @Vim  Just because we don't know any other societies in which those options would be viable doesn't make the choice socially influenced.  That question is probably best left to philosophers than mathematicians.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  It just depends on how you hold the camera.  Remember that we're looking at a 2d projection of a 3d image.  If you play around with a set of axes in a program like mathematica or maple, or even as simple as geogebra, you can easily get any of these images depending on where you put the camera.

That was my point about choosing surfaces that are most easily visualized under the given axes.  It's not necessarily easy, but it can be done.

Comment: @RobertShort Not to dispute your opinion, but as Henning Makholm pointed out, the pictures as we see should be "orthogonal projections" of these axis, in which I think mathematics must play a rôle.

Comment: @RobertShort In real life is there any chance that we can get a projection where, say, $\alpha=150,\beta=150,\gamma=60$?

Comment: What are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24578/discussion-between-robert-short-and-vim).